# How to make popup grow up in silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, popup

I'm having a problem with combobox popup (not sure if it's a problem of combobox). First when i click it, dropdown popup opens correct - upwards(there are about 50 items in it, and combobox is located in the bottom of the page, if it goes downwards, there would be only 5 items visible). But then if i select any item, and them open it again - it will open downwards and put items in a scroll. So how can I fix this and force popup open in the desired direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, what I've done - I subscribed to SizeChanged event of the Border element which is a child of Popup.Child canvas. In that method, I'm calculating space below and above the combo box and then setting Top offset using Canvas.SetTop method to that border and it's MaxHeight. Maybe I will post some code later.

Answer (score 0):

Are you setting the "MaxDropDownHeight" at some point?  By default it is infinity but maybe setting to hard # greater than # in combo box might help.

Also I just tested this in SL4/Firefox and the combo box pops up each time (with or without a selected item).  What version of SL are you using?

Comment: I'm using SL4 What means # greater than #? Greater than what?

Comment: Sorry, what I meant was try setting the MaxDropDownHeight to a number larger than the number of items in your list. You mention 50 items are in your combo box, so set MaxDropDownHeight = 51.  I saw a similar post to what you are describing but it had no dates or SL version mentioned so have no idea of what version it was taking about ... and no answer other than it is was "bug" and to use diff control (but no reference regarding a bug# or something to indicate that is was a logged as such at microsoft)

Answer (score 0):

I was having this exact same issue (actually with Silverlight 5, but the same behavior nonetheless).  I tried various things with MaxDropDownHeight but that did not correct the problem.

@Walker the approach you mentioned in your answer sounded promising but I was not able to tell from your description how you actually implemented that.

In any case, I found a rather unlikely solution. I discovered that if I populated my ComboBox with *ComboBoxItems* instead of a collection of custom objects, then the dropdown/selection/direction issue does not occur. I've posted an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11692600/633155) that goes into a little more detail.